# How do I make a thread wait without polling?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have question about multi threading in c++. I have a scenario as follows

```
void ThreadedRead(int32_t thread_num, BinReader reader) {
    while (!reader.endOfData) {
        thread_buckets[thread_num].clear();
        thread_buckets[thread_num] = reader.readnextbatch()
        thread_flags[thread_num] = THREAD_WAITING;
        while (thread_flags[thread_num] != THREAD_RUNNING) {
            // wait until awakened
            if (thread_flags[thread_num] != THREAD_RUNNING) {
                //go back to sleep
            }
        }
    }
    thread_flags[thread_num] = THREAD_FINISHED;
}
```

No section of the above code writes or access memory shared between threads. Each thread is assigned a thread_num and a unique reader object that it may use to read data.

I want the main thread to be able to notify a thread that is in the THREAD_WAITING state that his state has been changed back to THREAD_RUNNING and he needs to do some work. I don't want to him to keep polling his state.

I understand conditional vars and mutexes can help me. But I'm not sure how to use them because I don't want to acquire or need a lock. How can the mainthread blanket notify all waiting threads that they are now free to read more data?

EDIT:
Just in case anyone needs more details

1) reader reads some files
2) thread_buckets is a vector of vectors of uint16
3) threadflags is a int vector

they have all been resized appropriately

Comment: Just use a condition variable, the lock is required for the cv because otherwise a data race could occur when calling cv.wait() or cv.notify().

Comment: but no data is being accessed in a shared fashion? every thread has its own data members that it manipulates . I want them to run in a non mutually exclusive fashion. I just want them to wait till the main thread says it is okay for them to go ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize that you wrote that you wanted to avoid condition variables and locks. On the other hand you mentioned that this was because you were not sure about how to use them. Please consider the following example to get the job done without polling:

The trick with the condition variables is that a single `condition_variable` object together with a single `mutex` object will do the management for you including the handling of the `unique_lock` objects in the worker threads. Since you tagged your question as C++ I assume you are talking about C++11 (or higher) multithreading (I guess that C-pthreads may work similarly). Your code could be as follows:

```
// compile for C++11 or higher

#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

// objects visible to both master and workers:
std::condition_variable cvr;
std::mutex              mtx;

void ThreadedRead(int32_t thread_num, BinReader reader) {
    while (!reader.endOfData) {
        thread_buckets[thread_num].clear();
        thread_buckets[thread_num] = reader.readnextbatch()

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock(mtx);
        // This lock will be managed by the condition variable!

        thread_flags[thread_num] = THREAD_WAITING;
        while (thread_flags[thread_num] == THREAD_WAITING) {
            cvr.wait(myLock);
        // ...must be in a loop as shown because of potential spurious wake-ups
        }
    }
    thread_flags[thread_num] = THREAD_FINISHED;
}
```

To (re-)activate the workers from a master thread:

```
{ // block...
// step 1: usually make sure that there is no worker still preparing itself at the moment
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> someLock(mtx);
  // (in your case this would not cover workers currently busy with reader.readnextbatch(),
  // these would be not re-started this time...)

// step 2: set all worker threads that should work now to THREAD_RUNNING
  for (...looping over the worker's flags...) {
    if (...corresponding worker should run now...) {
      flag = THREAD_RUNNING;
    }
  }

// step 3: signalize the workers to run now
  cvr.notify_all();

} // ...block, releasing someLock
```

Notice:

- If you just want to trigger all sleeping workers you should control them with a single flag instead of a container of flags.
- If you want to trigger single sleeping workers but it doesn't matter which one consider the `.notify_one()` member function instead of `.notify_all()`. Note as well that also in this case a single mutex/condition_variable pair is sufficient.
- The flags should better be placed in an `atomic` object such as a global `std::atomic<int>` or maybe for finer control in a `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>`.
- A good introduction to `std::condition_variable` which also inspired the suggested solution is given in: [cplusplus website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/?kw=condition_variable)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a few issues. For one thing, you do not need the conditional inside of your loop:

```
while (thread_flags[thread_num] != THREAD_RUNNING);
```

will work by itself. As soon as that condition is false, the loop will exit.

If all you want to do is avoid checking thread_flags as quickly as possible, just put a yield in the loop:

```
while (thread_flags[thread_num] != THREAD_RUNNING) yield(100);
```

This will cause the thread to yield the CPU so that it can do other things while the thread waits for its state to change. This will make make the overhead for polling close to negligible. You can experiment with the sleep duration to find a good value. 100ms is probably on the long side.

Depending on what causes the thread state to change, you could have the thread poll that condition/value directly (with a sleep in still) and not bother with states at all.

There are a lot of options here. If you look up reader threads you can probably find just what you want; having a separate reader thread is very common.

Comment: but the task in question coul be completed a lot quicker than 1000ms I just want to wait as long as needed till task completion :(

Comment: Agreed on both counts. I updated my answer to use 100ms instead (still high but probably closer to what you'd want) and to use yield() as a generic thread-yielding function to make it plainer that the thread should not take up CPU resources while it waits.